# Rancher 2.0.4 multipleIP on worker

Tags: centos, kubernetes, rancher-2

I setup multiple IPs on host with working node for rancher 2
Host is pingable from outside world on each of this IP. But not doesn't see this IP and if I configure hostport to IP:port format, I get still connection to base IP of this node. If start two containers with the same port but different ext IP, accessible only last started container.

Everything that I found about multiple IP on rancher connected to rancher 1.6. But rancher changes architecture from version 1.6 to 2.0 and now is based on kubernetes.

So the question is, is it a bug for rancher, or it's not possible at all due to kubernetes foundation?

Answer (score 0):

probably there is only hostPort param available in rancher, and hostIP is missing